# Selecting and Highlighting an Item from List View

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I would like to select and highlight an item from a list view control and am using the following code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>


int main() {
    //Hardcoded Handle to the ListView Windows of Add Printer Dialog
    HWND hwndListView = (HWND)0x000206D6; 
    DWORD dwProcessID;
    ::GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwndListView, &dwProcessID );
    HANDLE process=OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_VM_WRITE|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessID); 

    LVITEM lvi;

    LVITEM* _lvi=(LVITEM*)VirtualAllocEx(process, NULL, sizeof(LVITEM), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE); 

    lvi.state = LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED ;
    lvi.stateMask = LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED ;
    lvi.mask = LVIF_STATE;

    WriteProcessMemory(process, _lvi, &lvi, sizeof(LVITEM), NULL); 
    ::SendMessage(hwndListView, LVM_SETITEMSTATE, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)_lvi); 
    VirtualFreeEx(process, _lvi, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
}
```

The result I am getting is

[image]

instead of the item getting selected and highlighted

[image]

Please let me know what might be going wrong

Comment: Why dont you write test app with ListView and try to select item in it? This way you will be able to debug it what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: Maybe ListView is not in focus?

Comment: @marcin_j: Can you please elaborate what you mean by writing an App with ListView?

Comment: @AlexFarber: I tried adding another Line `::SetFocus(hwndListView)` but that didn't help

Comment: What happens if you manually set the focus to ListView in the window - by using Mouse or Tab key?

Comment: @AlexFarber: Do you mean after running the above code? Well after running the above code, if I select the Header `Manufacturer`, the item gets highlighted as shown in the second picture.

Comment: OK, this means, the problem is the focus. ListView has some style which allows to keep an items highlighted even when the control is not in focus. Try to set this style. Or you need to find the way to make `SetFocus` working, but this is different question. The problem is not in item state.

Comment: There are restrictions on which processes can set focus on a window, and chances are that the app selecting the ListView items does not satisfy those restrictions while the dialog is active. For example, the HWND being focused must be attached to the calling thread's message queue. So the highlighting app will have to use `AttachThreadInput()` before calling `SetFocus()` on another app's windows.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I believe this is the closest answer to my question. If you post it as an answer, I would accept it and give due credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are restrictions on which processes can set focus on a window, and chances are that the app selecting the ListView items does not satisfy those restrictions while the dialog is active. For example, the HWND being focused must be attached to the calling thread's message queue. So the highlighting app will have to use `AttachThreadInput()` before calling `SetFocus()` on another app's windows.