# In Inno Setup, how can I set which component gets an initial focus on "Select Components" page

Tags: inno-setup

When the `wpSelectComponents` page is shown, I'd like to set focus to a particular item/component in the list.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ItemIndex` property of `WizardForm.ComponentsList`, like:

```pascal
WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemIndex := 2;
```

---

Note that focus of the list item is not rendered, until the list itself receives a focus:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then 
  begin
    WizardForm.ActiveControl := WizardForm.ComponentsList;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WinAPI to achieve this.

Unfortunately I could not find any Pascal example so have a look on this C++ code: [Selecting and Highlighting an Item from List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589921/selecting-and-highlighting-an-item-from-list-view).

Calling this code from Inno Setup requires to call WinApi dlls functions so maybe writing this feature as small C++ plugin could be easier.